# Can this code be shorter? Bots, instructions and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, readline

The idea for this task comes from Advent of Code, Day 10. Bots manipulate chips with numbers. Instructions are given as follows (they are located in a *txt* file).

```
bot 1 gives low to output 1 and high to bot 0
value 5 goes to bot 2
bot 0 gives low to output 2 and high to output 0
bot 2 gives low to bot 1 and high to bot 0
value 3 goes to bot 1
value 2 goes to bot 2
```

I had to write a function read_file(filename) that reads the file and returns a pair (tuple). The first element is the initial state and the second are the instructions.

As an example:

The initial state in this example is: `{1: [3], 2: [5, 2]}`

and the instructions are `{0: (('output', 2), ('output', 0)), 1: (('output', 1), ('bot', 0)), 2: (('bot', 1), ('bot', 0))}`

This is how I solved it.

```
bots = dict()
instructions = dict()
with open("example.txt") as f:
    linez = f.readlines()

for line in linez:
    line = line.strip()
    data = line.split(" ")
    if line.startswith("value"):
        value = int(data[1])
        bot = int(data[5])

        if bot not in bots:
            bots[bot] = []
        bots[bot].append(value)

    elif line.startswith("bot"):
        bot = int(data[1])
        low = (data[5], int(data[6]))
        high = (data[10], int(data[11]))
        instructions[bot] = (low, high)
```

I was wondering, if there was a **shorter** way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you looking for a *shorter* or *faster* code? This is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, meant shorter. Will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

as the comment above says - not sure if you want *shorter* or *faster* code.

What you can do for a shorter code is to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) so you dont have to explicitly check if a certain key in dictionary exists already:

```
from collections import defaultdict
bots = defaultdict(list) # the param says what should be the default value

# the following three lines will be replaced with the line below
# if bot not in bots:
#     bots[bot] = []
# bots[bot].append(value)
bots[bot].append(value)
```

and then a small thing - the following two lines line = `line.strip(); data = line.split(" ")` can be replaced with `data = line.strip().split()`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
    linez = f.readlines()

for line in linez:
    # code here
```

with:

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # code here
```

It's both shorter (well, not by much but...) and more memory efficient ;)